# How could alert TFS on specific query when state changed?

Tags: tfs, tfs-power-tools

I use Alert Explorer using Team Foundation Server Power Tools. My senario is when a State of spacific workItem Changed an email send to users.but when i want to create my query on some fields that I added them to my workItemType befor , only Possible Operator is (Changed-ChangeFrom-ChangeTo) but I want operator (=,<>,...).Why this field didnt have that operator? what should I do?

Comment: I think this documents a similar problem you maybe having: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/tfspowertools/thread/52791dff-ef22-440b-ab7f-3031a5dbfb27

Comment: I'm having the same problem in TFS 2012

Answer (score 0):

Only the core fields got the operators you want. You can't do a lot about it, only hope, that it will be implemented some day.